# Save Php LDap Session for later use

Tags: php, codeigniter, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a php web application where I have to authenticate users with company's active directory. That part is clear, the problem is I need to maintain the session for later use. Like I need to check if some userID exists in AD or not. Admin will sign in once and then in later stages he needs to verify if xyz users exist or not. I am using following for login:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

Any idea how can we maintain session so that Admin doesn't have to login on each user lookup?

Thanks

Comment: I believe anonymous lookup is not enabled in AD.

Comment: Can you not just cache $ldapconn? Not an expert on it but thats a first thought.

Comment: Nope, that can't be done as it is a reference, not an object.